# How to include rows with MySQL COUNT that are 0?

Tags: mysql, count

I'm using the following query which returns the result as below:

```
SELECT  subnets.subnet_id , INET_NTOA(  subnets.address ) AS inet_address, subnet_masks.hosts, COUNT(addresses.STATUS) AS status_count
FROM subnets
LEFT JOIN subnet_masks ON subnets.mask_id = subnet_masks.mask_id
LEFT JOIN addresses ON subnets.subnet_id = addresses.subnet_id
WHERE addresses.status = 'allocated'
GROUP BY subnet_id      
ORDER BY subnets.address



subnet_id   inet_address    hosts   status_count
91          10.10.10.0      65534   3
71          192.168.1.0     254     6
90          192.168.10.0    254     1
```

However I want it return the rows that count 0 too, much like this:

```
subnet_id   inet_address    hosts   status_count
91          10.10.10.0      65534   3
76          172.128.0.0     254     0
71          192.168.1.0     254     6
90          192.168.10.0    254     1
```

I read that it may be a problem with my JOINs so I've tried a number of different ones and I'm getting the same result. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is filtering out records... move it to your `LEFT JOIN` to resolve the issue:

```
SELECT  subnets.subnet_id , INET_NTOA(  subnets.address ) AS inet_address, subnet_masks.hosts, COUNT(addresses.STATUS) AS status_count
FROM subnets
LEFT JOIN subnet_masks ON subnets.mask_id = subnet_masks.mask_id
LEFT JOIN addresses ON subnets.subnet_id = addresses.subnet_id AND addresses.status = 'allocated'
GROUP BY subnet_id      
ORDER BY subnets.address
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT  subnets.subnet_id , INET_NTOA(  subnets.address ) AS inet_address,  
    subnet_masks.hosts, COUNT(addresses.STATUS) AS status_count
FROM subnets
LEFT JOIN subnet_masks ON subnets.mask_id = subnet_masks.mask_id
LEFT JOIN addresses ON subnets.subnet_id = addresses.subnet_id
    and addresses.status = 'allocated'
GROUP BY subnet_id      
ORDER BY subnets.address
```

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause is specifying that address.status = 'allocated' but the rows with status_count equal to 0 don't have an address, and therefore cannot have this status.

Answer (score 0):

Your left join is wrong It should be Like this

```
SELECT  subnets.subnet_id , INET_NTOA(  subnets.address ) AS inet_address, subnet_masks.hosts, COUNT(addresses.STATUS) AS status_count
FROM subnets
LEFT JOIN subnet_masks ON subnets.mask_id = subnet_masks.mask_id
LEFT JOIN addresses ON subnets.subnet_id = addresses.subnet_id AND addresses.status = allocated'
GROUP BY subnet_id      
ORDER BY subnets.address
```